# Convergence and power means

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, means

If a non-negative sequence of numbers converges to some limit, does the n'th power mean of the sequence (constructed as a limit of finite power means on the first N entries) also converge to the same limit?

If so, is this a special case of any more powerful, general theorem?

For instance, does it hold for any absolutely convergent sequence and some suitably large class of means?

Comment: The constant sequence $\{2,2,2,\dots\}$ suggests you might need an $n^\text{th}$ root wrapped around your sum of $n^\text{th}$ powers.  If you put that root in, you're talking about [$\ell^p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#.E2.84.93p_spaces) and asking how the $\ell^p$-norm of a sequence varies with $p$.

Comment: The power mean has the n'th root put in the definition, or else it wouldn't be a mean. Conversely, the $\ell^p$ norm is not a mean - for example, the 2nd power mean is root-mean-squared, whereas the $\ell^2$ norm is root-sum-squared.

Comment: Also, to be very specific, I want the n'th root of the *mean* of the n'th powers - the n'th power mean. In contrast, the $\ell^p$ norm is the p'th root of the *sum* of the p'th powers.

Comment: Logarithm + cesaro lemma?